# How to suppress XML object message from output in powershell

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, ssh

I would like to return the node addresses only with

`ssh $thishost powershell -Command {Get-InitiatorPort| select NodeAddress }`

but I am getting XML messages before and after the output I want.

Here is the output:

```
#< CLIXML

NodeAddress
-----------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><Obj S="progress" RefId="0"><TN RefId="0
"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N="SourceId">1</I64><PR N="Record"
><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></
PR></MS></Obj><Obj S="progress" RefId="1"><TNRef RefId="0" /><MS><I64 N="SourceId">2</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Preparing m
odules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj><O
bj S="progress" RefId="2"><TNRef RefId="0" /><MS><I64 N="SourceId">3</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Get-InitiatorPort | select
NodeAddress</AV><AI>2034432450</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>100</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>0</SR><SD>1/1 completed</SD></PR></
MS></Obj></Objs>
```

The same command does not produce the XML messages when I ran it on the host. The message only appears when running the command in a ssh session on a client. I have no idea why these messages are showing in the output.

Comment: Without knowing the shell you connect to, try: `ssh $thishost powershell -Command "Get-InitiatorPort| select NodeAddress"`

Comment: The extra text looks like it's coming from one of PowerShell's output streams - the xml for example contains the message "Preparing modules for first use.". Can you try prefixing your script with ```$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"```, i.e. ```ssh $thishost powershell -Command {$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"; Get-InitiatorPort| select NodeAddress }```